# Unable to add .asmx files as web references in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, configuration, sharepoint-2010, performancepoint

When i try to add a web reference to my VS2010 project i encounter the following error.(the service is running fine , infact VS2010 detects it on its own when looking for services hosted on the system )

```
The document at the url http://localhost/_vti_bin/PPS/PPSAuthoringService.asmx 
was not recognized as a known document type.
The error message from each known type may help you fix the problem:
- Report from 'XML Schema' is 'The document format is not recognized
 (the content type is 'text/html; char
```

Comment: its a sharepoint webservice , plus i dont think its an issue with the service as my teammate can perform the action from her system

Comment: This service is generated automatically when sharepoint is installed , i have no say in which folder it goes to